# How to write generic regex to extract the data in ExtractText?

Tags: regex, csv, apache-nifi

My present data like below,It contains 100 rows

```
1,Ads,,12,CDMA,,12
2,,12,14,CDMA,,12
..
...
100,DVS,13,,CDMA,12,22
```

i have using GetFile-->SplitText-->ExtractText to split the data in row using 10 regex attributes for my present data.

```
For example my one of the input regex is (.+),(.+),,(.+),(.+),(.+) It will split the regex.1,regex.2 upto regex.5
```

For this data in ExtractText processor i have given 10 regex attributes to match all values in present data.

In Future there is another 100 rows will be added to present data.So i have to write regex attribute for future 100 lines also.

I need to add expression language support for all columns in extracted data in Processor also.

Is it possible to give common regex for all data in ExtractText processor?

Is there is anyother way to extract the data by delimiter like comma,pipe symbol in NIFI?

Any help appreciated.

Please anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find common regex for extract my data from csv file.,

```
([^,]*?),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)
```

It could be  huge expensive if it might be better than this   `(.+),(.+),,(.+),(.+),(.+)`

It may be helpful for someone.